# Why am I getting 'ValueError: too many values to unpack'?

Tags: python

So I have some python code -

```
list1 = ["Anthony", "Sean"] # define a table to use while testing

def IsInArray(val, *tab):   # define function to check
    for v, in tab:
        if v == val:
            return true
    return false

if IsInArray("Anthony", list1) == true:        # testing it
    print("Anthony is in list1")

if IsInArray("Charles", list1) == true:
    print("Charles is in list1")
```

but it says `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. I don't understand and the other threads are too different to understand how to fix this.

Comment: Remove that comma. And truthy value is `True`, falsy is `False` (upper case).

Comment: What is the purpose of the function `IsInArray` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `in` operator:

```
if "Anthony" in list1:        # testing it
    print("Anthony is in list1")

if "Charles" in list1:
    print("Charles is in list1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma and remove the `*` operator if you provide a list as second argument (and `True`, not `true`):

```
# def IsInArray(val, *tab):
def IsInArray(val, tab):   # define function to check
    for v in tab:
        if val in v:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks, I just need to replace the other lowercases with upercases now.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 mistakes in the function (extra comma, `True`/`False`, and the conditional expression). Maybe this is what you mean to

```
def IsInArray(val, *tab):   # define function to check
    for v in tab:
        if val in v:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra comma that should be removed:

```
    for v, in tab:
```

After this - note that there is no such thing in Python as `true` or `false` - it's `True` and `False`.

I can spot new issue - even with all suggestions:

```
def IsInArray(val, *tab):   # define function to check
    for v in tab:
        if v == val:
            return True
    return False


IsInArray("Anthony", "Anthony", "Sean")
Out[6]: True

IsInArray("Anthony", ["Anthony", "Sean"])
Out[7]: False
```

In order to take a list as argument, remove asterix (`*`) in definition:

```
def IsInArray(val, tab):
```